# How to find what git repo an Azure Function is set up to pull from?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a few Azure functions and they are setup to deploy from my GitHub repos. How can I find what repo it is connect to in the portal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click your function app

-> Go to `Platform features` tab

-> click `All settings`

-> `Overview`

-> `GitHub Project` label on the right

Comment: We're aware that it is a little hard to find, and will improve this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Via [Kudu APIs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) (just hit these endpoints with your browser after logging in to the Azure Portal):

**/api/settings**:

```
GET https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings

{
  "deployment_branch": "master",
  "ScmType": "GitHub",
  "branch": "dev",
  ...
}
```

**/api/deployments**:

```
GET https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments

{
  "id": "7c7b7fad2c6ea993671deccc45ebc482ea4355c1",
  ...
  "author": "snobu",
  "deployer": "GitHub",
  "message": "Fix removed one too many dependencies",
  "site_name": "gifinator"
  ...
},
{
  <<previous commit info>>
},
...
```

I believe the actual URL of the GitHub repository is in the Webhook payload and Portal settings, not in Kudu, but i could be wrong.

Comment: I don't see the git endpoint there. Great clue, will keep digging.